# MYSQL 5.5 - To write a file with insert statements that should ask for Input and inserts

Tags: mysql

I am new to Mysql.

I have a file with many Insert statements to insert username, password and other user details.

i have to run this in mysql command promp.

When running the insert file in mysql, the command should ask me enter the username and I should the user name, and it should aske me for password  and other details.

In this way all the insert statement should get the values.

How i should write the batch file, any help would be appreciated.
thanks,
Sridevi

Comment: This is related to mysql, I need to create a Script for mysql that can be run in mysql command prompt with output messages and input.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you CAN`T do this using MySQL & simple SQL Statements. The best solution is to use a programming language like PHP.
Or if you have all statements, you can put them all in a SQL file & use mysqldump to batch execute them.

Comment: Can you provide an example to use mysqldump ?